# I need to get the unique values from the tags field

Tags: python, django, mongodb

My sample record:

```
[   
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "status": "one",
        "unit": [
        ],
        "child": [],
        "element": [
            "6604"
        ],
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2",
            "tag3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "name2",
        "status": "one",
        "unit": [
        ],
        "child": [],
        "element": [
            "6604"
        ],
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2",
            "tag3",
            "tag4"
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried in this way to get
tagsdata = dbname.distinct('tags.values')

expecting the output: `"tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4"`

All unique values form the key field.

Comment: you got a record with a query. How about you filter unique tags at the python level instead of making `DB Query`?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a document database.  It will never return a bare string or a list of strings.

Using aggregation you might

- $unwind the tags array
- $group using $addToSet to keep the unique tags
- $project to sort the returned array

That pipeline might look like:

```
[
  {$unwind: "$tags"},
  {$group: {
      _id: null,
      tags: {$addToSet: "$tags"}
  }},
  {$project: {
    _id: 0,
    tags: {$sortArray: {
        input: "$tags",
        sortBy: 1
    }}
  }}
]
```

Which returns:

```
[{"tags": [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"]}]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ezjN2EB9CQV)

Answer (score -1):

add
`unique:true`
In mongoDb model and while inserting data do check if data doesnt exists with same name with : `DB.findOne`

Comment: it will just prevent duplicate creation and the question is about filtering from duplicates and displaying unique only which is a different thing I guess.